# Cannot find JsonObject class

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet that takes a parameter from the request and sends a `JsonObject` as a response.

My problem that every time that I tried to use the `PrintWriter` class (I tried even to print simple string as a test), the servlet starts but never returns a response. My second problem is that I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject
```

What package contains the JsonObject?

The servlet code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String user = request.getParameter("param1"); // I need this later ...
    System.out.println("do get called ");
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    org.json.JSONObject json = new org.json.JSONObject();
    try {
        json.put("Mobile",123);
        json.put("Name", "ManojSarnaik");
        out.print(json.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        out.flush();
    } finally{
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd guess that your two issues are one in the same. You are not getting a response because your method is throwing an exception. The library you are looking for (judging by the `org.json` package) is: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code should be worked fine except for this exception '[ClassNotFoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html)' that means that the `org.json.JSONObject` aren't in the classpath and on the build for project, make sure that you import by `maven`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20150729</version>
</dependency>
```

or [JAR file](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) for the class [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html).